# Re-size the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe that is a 5252 rows x 3 columns

data look something like this

```
   X       Y      Z
   1       1      2
   1       2      4
   1       3    3.5
   2      13      4
   1       4      3
   2      14    3.5
   3      14      2
   3      15      1
   4      16     .5
   4      18      2
   .       .      .
   .       .      .
   .       .      .
1508     751      1
1508     669      1
1508     686    2.5
```

I want to convert it so the userid is the rows and itemid is the column and Z is the data correspond to X and Y. Something like this:

```
       1  2    3   4  5  6  13   14  15  16  17   18  669  686

   1   2  4  3.5   3  0  0   0    0   0   0   0    0    0    0 
   2   0  0    0   0  0  0   4  4.5   0   0   0    0    0    0
   3   0  0    0   0  0  0   0    2   0   0   0    0    0    0
   4   0  0    0   0  0  0   0    0   0  .5   0    2    0    0
   .
   .
   .
1508   0  0    0   0  0  0   0    0   0   0   0    0    1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library.

You need [pd.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) function. If the dataframe is called `df`, then you need:

```
pd.pivot_table(data=df, index="x", columns="y", values="z", aggfunc=sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `pd.pivot_table()` and use `fillna(0)`. Recreating your sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4], 'Y': [1,2,3,4,13,14,14,15,16], 'Z': [2,4,3.5,3,4,3.5,2,1,.5]})
```

Gives:

```
   X   Y    Z
0  1   1  2.0
1  1   2  4.0
2  1   3  3.5
3  1   4  3.0
4  2  13  4.0
5  2  14  3.5
6  3  14  2.0
7  3  15  1.0
8  4  16  0.5
```

Then using `pd.pivot_table()`:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values='Z', index=['X'], columns=['Y']).fillna(0)
```

Yields:

```
Y   1    2    3    4    13   14   15   16
X                                        
1  2.0  4.0  3.5  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  4.0  3.5  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  1.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5
```